# How to pass a value from html to css file

Tags: html, css, variables

I am trying to pass a value from my html into my css file to display the tank value in a percentage. Both current html and css below

- Without the use of anything other than html and css

```css
#tank-container {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: clear;
  border-radius: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float : left;
}

#tank-content {
  height: attr(tank-content); /* edit this */
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: green;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 120px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tank-container">
  <div id="tank-content">
     <p tank-content="50%"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN6pQ.png)

Comment: Why do you want to add the percentage in the html page? Just add it to the CSS file instead.

Comment: @Barry I am trying to pass it through like this,                                   
                               <div id="tank-container">
                                    <div id="tank-content">
                                        <p tank-content="@t.getPercentage"></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                                                      And this won't work in the css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do with `attr( tank-content )` but, for now, that's only useful for populating the `content` property of a pseudo-element.

**Reference Mozilla's MDN article: [css/attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)**

> The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but support for properties other than content is experimental.

A potential solution might be to set an inline `style = "height: @t.getPercentage"` attribute on the `#tank-content`. It's not the clean, custom attribute solution you were looking for but it allows you to set the height, in percentage, directly in the HTML without writing *n* number of incremental CSS rules or using JavaScript.

```css
#tank-container {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: clear;
  border-radius: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float : left;
}

#tank-content {
  height: attr(tank-content); /* edit this */
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: green;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 120px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tank-container">
  <div id="tank-content" style="height: 50%;">
     <p tank-content="50%"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```